# How to read .fit file from the disk

Tags: c#, asp.net, garmin

I have requirement to create asp .net application that will upload garmin .fit files and store it to Database.

I'm trying to use Garmin Communicator Plugin API to read .fit file from a disk, but I'm unable to read data that is located on my hard disk(I do not have any Garmin Device).

Do you know is this possible to achive with Garmin Communicator Plugin API and how it could be done?Or you think there is some other possibility?

App should be something like this one

http://www.goodrunguide.co.uk/FITFileUpload.asp?FileUpload=1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may have a look at the [fit-sdk](http://www.thisisant.com/resources/fit).

Check also this excellent converter to GPX format *(link is dead as of Aug-2017)*: <s>https://code.google.com/p/speelterrein/</s>

Comment: Yes, that would be the thing I was looking for. Thanks